# import data from csv and create list of Active Directory users

Tags: python, powershell, csv, active-directory

hey so i am trying to make the same script from powershell in python but i cant get it right maybe you can help me out,
so the script is like that:

1. opens a csv file with the users information
2. create users for each row in the csv file

the csv looks like this:

[image]

the powershell scripts works fine looks like this:

```
# import module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
# create new password
$securedpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "abc-123" -AsPlainText -Force
#import csv

$filepath = Read-Host -Prompt "please enter csv path"

#import the file into a variable

$users = Import-Csv $filepath

# loop all rows to gather information
foreach ($user in $users) {

# gather user information
$fname = $user.'first name'
$lname = $user.'last name'
$oupath = $user.'ou'
#creat new ad user from csv file
New-ADUser -name "$fname $lname" -GivenName $fname -Surname $lname -UserPrincipalName "$fname.$lname" -Path $oupath -AccountPassword $securedpassword -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true
# echo output
echo "account created for $fname $lname in $oupath"
}
```

and in python like this:

```
#import csv and active directory module

import csv
from pyad import *

def createuserfromcsv():
    #takes full file path for test: c:\newusers.csv
    file = input('please type your file path + file: ')
    
    data = open(file,encoding="utf-8")
    
    csv_data = csv.reader(data)
    
    data_lines = list(csv_data)

    pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="DC-01-Training.Udemy.training",username="Administrator",password="abc-123")



    for line in data_lines[1:]:
        user = line[0]
    for line in data_lines[1:]:
        oupath = line[2]
ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn(oupath)
new_user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.create(user,ou,password="abc-123")


print(user)
print(oupath)
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: why is every line in your csv enclosed in square brackets???

Comment: no its a spreadsheet what you see its the output of : print(data_lines)

Comment: So what you show us is not a csv file at all.. Please edit your question, and put in VALID csv data.

Comment: ok now i added picture of the original csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i made it ,works both with or without function:

```
import csv
from pyad import *
def createuserfromcsv():
    #takes full file path
    file = input('please type your file path + file: ')
    data = open(file,encoding="utf-8")
    csv_data = csv.reader(data)
    data_lines = list(csv_data)
    #load admin information
    pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="DC-01-Training.Udemy.training",username="Administrator",password="abc-123")

    for line in data_lines[1:]:
        user = line[0]
        oupath = line[2]
        ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn(oupath)
        pyad.aduser.ADUser.create(user,ou,password="abc-123")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Step 1: Import the ActiveDirectory module and connect to the AD server
    
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    
    $ad_user = "user@example.com"
    $ad_password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $ad_credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ad_user, $ad_password
    $ad_domain = "example.com"
    
    Connect-AzureAD -Credential $ad_credential -TenantId $ad_domain
    
    # Step 2: Read the CSV file into a variable as an array of objects
    
    $records = Import-Csv -Path "records.csv"
    
    # Step 3: Iterate over the array of objects and create AD users
    
    foreach ($record in $records) {
      $first_name = $record.first_name
      $last_name = $record.last_name
      $email = $record.email
      $password = $record.password
      
      # Create the AD user
      New-AzureADUser -AccountEnabled $true -DisplayName "$first_name $last_name" -PasswordProfile @{ Password = $password; ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = $false } -UserPrincipalName $email -GivenName $first_name -Surname $last_name -MailNickname $email
      
      # Set additional attributes for the user
      Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$email'").ObjectId -MobilePhone $record.mobile_phone -StreetAddress $record.street_address -City $record.city -State $record.state -PostalCode $record.postal_code -Country $record.country
    }
    
    # Step 4: Save the changes to the AD server
    
    Save-AzureAD
    
    Write-Host "Import completed successfully!"
```

1. Save the script to a file with a .ps1 extension, such as Import-ADUsers.ps1.
2. Modify the script to set the appropriate values for the following variables:
3. $ou: This is the distinguished name (DN) of the organizational unit (OU) in which you want to create the new users.
4. $csvFile: This is the path to the CSV file that contains the user records you want to import.
5. Ensure that the CSV file has the appropriate columns, as specified in the script.
6. Open a PowerShell window and navigate to the directory where the script is saved.
7. Run the script using the following command: .\Import-ADUsers.ps1
   The script will read the CSV file, create a new user object for each record in the file, and set the specified attributes for each user.

   Note that you will need to have the Active Directory module installed on your machine, and you will need to run the script with administrative privileges.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Step 1: Install the required python modules

!pip install pyad
!pip install pandas

# Step 2: Import the necessary modules in your script

import pyad
import pandas as pd

# Step 3: Connect to the AD server

ad_user = "user@example.com"
ad_password = "password"
ad_domain = "example.com"

pyad.set_defaults(username=ad_user, password=ad_password)
ad_server = pyad.adserver.ADServer.from_domain_name(ad_domain)

# Step 4: Read the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv("records.csv")

# Step 5: Iterate over the rows of the DataFrame and create AD users

ou = "OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com"  # The distinguished name of the AD organizational unit where you want to create the users

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  first_name = row["first_name"]
  last_name = row["last_name"]
  email = row["email"]
  password = row["password"]
  
  # Create the AD user
  user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.create(name=f"{first_name} {last_name}", upn=email, password=password, ou=ou)
  
  # Set additional attributes for the user
  user.update_attribute("givenName", first_name)
  user.update_attribute("sn", last_name)
  user.update_attribute("mail", email)

# Step 6: Save the changes to the AD server

ad_server.commit()

print("Import completed successfully!")
```

**This script performs the following steps:**

1. Installs the required python modules pyad and pandas using the pip command.
2. Imports the pyad and pandas modules.
3. Connects to the AD server using the provided domain name and credentials. The pyad.set_defaults() function is used to set the default username and password for the connection. The pyad.adserver.ADServer.from_domain_name() function is used to create an AD server object based on the provided domain name.
4. Reads the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame using the pandas.read_csv() function.
5. Iterates over the rows of the DataFrame using the df.iterrows() function. For each row, the script extracts the values of the relevant columns (e.g. first name, last name, email, password) and stores them in variables.
6. Creates a new AD user using the pyad.aduser.ADUser.create() method. The name argument specifies the full name of the user, the upn argument specifies the user principal name (email address), and the password argument specifies the user's password. The ou argument specifies the distinguished name of the AD organizational unit where you want to create the user.
7. Sets additional attributes for the user using the `user.update_attribute()